# How to change JA3 token in the rust reqwest crate

Tags: http, ssl, rust, tls1.2, reqwest

so my question is how do I change the JA3 token in the reqwest crate rust? I tried looking in the docs but got no help. If there is a crate in rust that allows this then please let me know. It will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the variables used to calculate the JA3 fingerprint are [well-documented](https://github.com/salesforce/ja3), you just need to change one of them. For example the list of supported ciphers.

For that you'll have to set up TLS manually and inject it into `ClientBuilder` via [`use_preconfigured_tls`](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/struct.ClientBuilder.html#method.use_preconfigured_tls).